# Dual sided uFL connections

Tags: antenna, wifi, microstrip

I am laying out a dual sided PCB, 1.6mm (62mil) thickness.  I'm wondering if I can drop a via on the feedline to a uFL connector and place another uFL on the other side.  Will this cause unacceptable signal reflections?

Additional info:
Design frequency is 2.4Ghz WiFi.  Board is a large LED sign (579mm x 186mm) which makes a 4-layer PCB cost prohibitive.  Because of this the feedline is not impedance-controlled, and it doesn't have a pi-network for impedance matching.  I understand that I can get away without impedance control as long as I keep the feedline very short.

Traces above ANT720 are RF grounds.  In addition entire area in brown box will be flooded with copper fill (GND) top and bottom, and stitched together with vias.  Traces that are visible are 0.5mm.

[image: uFL with via tap to secondary uFL]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it, and it might work... or it might not. In general, vias on feedlines are frowned upon because their impedance is hard to predict and will vary due to through-hole plating thickness.

Typically every RF device and trace is built for a [characteristic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_impedance). The moment you connect two uFL connectors to a third trace, you're implying that *three* devices will be connected, in essentially a "star" topology, which would likely skew the impedance right out of the operable range. It should work with only two devices connected, however, provided that trace is short. Still, adding the second uFL is adding inductance and capacitance to the feedline, which can alter it's performance.

It might be possible to get around this by painstakingly tuning each leg using tons of math, inductors, and capacitors, but this would require a [Vector Network Analyzer](https://www.tek.com/document/primer/what-vector-network-analyzer-and-how-does-it-work) or similar and prototyping revisions.

Also remember that a trace will start to behave as an antenna when it's length approaches 1/10th the wavelength. I can't tell how long that feedline is, but at 2.4GHz, the wavelength is about 125mm. So a 13mm long feedline at this frequency starts to become problematic (an "unintentional radiator.") Incidentally, 1/4 wavelength (31.25mm) would function very well as an antenna.

If the device / antenna comes with a suggested layout, it is highly recommended to stick to that.  Anything else is a gamble, and may require re-working and re-spinning the board.